# Rails checkboxes in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have added checkboxes through loops

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "cities[]", city.id %> <%= city.city_name %>
<% end %>
```

I have displayed them on page and now how can I get the checked value to show on the other page?

Comment: What "other page"?

Comment: you will need to show more code here.

Answer (score 0):

By MVC design, you should prepare whatever you want to display on your controller and display it on your view.

Comment: I have done that only. but dont know how to fetch value.